# the big O of while loop executed sum(n-1) time

Tags: algorithm, while-loop, big-o

**If someone could help me with:**

1- **what** is the time complexity (**Big O**) of **this code**?

2- if the big O of this code = O(n^2) then **which** is better **to use** (while like this code) **or** (two nested for loop)?

the code:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5]  // big O => O(1)
ll = list(l)  // big O => O(1)

a = 0  // big O => O(1)
b = 1  // big O => O(1)
x = 0  // big O => O(1)
y = 0  // big O => O(1)
 

while a < len(l)-1:  // big O  => O(?)
    
    x = l[a]  // big O => O(1)
    y = l[b]  // big O => O(1)

    if x > y :  // big O => O(1)

        ll[a] = 0   // big O => O(1)
        a += 1   // big O => O(1)
        b =a+1   // big O => O(1)
        
    elif b >= len(l)-1:   //big O => O(1)

        a += 1  // big O => O(1)
        b = a + 1  // big O => O(1)
        continue  // big O => O(?)
    
    else :  // big O => O(1)
        b += 1  // big O => O(1)
        continue   // big O => O(?)
        
print(ll) // big O => O(1)
```

In the **worst case** of above code make **while loop executed sum of `(n-1)` time for example:**

```
if n = 1 then while loop will execute 0 time
if n = 2 then while loop will execute 1 time
if n = 3 then while loop will execute 3 time
if n = 4 then while loop will execute 6 time
if n = 6 then while loop will execute 15 time
.
.
.
if n = k then while loop will execute sum(k-1) time
```

I hope my question is clear.

Comment: The sum `1+2+...+(n-1)` is in the order of `O(n^2)`. Therefore if your loop iterates this number of times (and does `O(1)` work in each iteration), the complexity is `O(n^2)`.

Comment: the code you provided will only run 2*n times: the line `i=count - 1` does nothing.

Comment: *"if n = 6 then while loop will execute 15 time"*: The code you provided is not doing what you say it does.  When n is 6, the loop makes 10 iterations. This makes your question ambiguous. What are you asking now? To align the code with the description? To align the description with the code? To analyse the complexity of the described algorithm? To analyse the complexity of the provided code?

Comment: @trincot, Sorry, I tried to find similar idea to the actual code. but actually it is wrong example. the actual code is to pass through list[a1, a2, a3, a4...,an] and compare each element (a) with the remaining elements in the list and if a< an then replace a in the list with special value. so for example if input list =[ 2, 1, 4, 3] and if a<an then replace a with (0) then 2<4 => 0 , 1<4 => 0, 4> 3 so Not( a<an) then it will be the same a =>4, 3 no more item in the list to compare so it will be the same also =>3   then the output list =[ 0 , 0 , 4, 3 ]. I hope my question is clear know.

Comment: Please update your question. Make sure also that it is clear what you ask about: the time complexity of a certain piece of code, or the problem you have to solve the code challenge, or still something else.

Comment: @trincot , I updated my question. I hope it is clear know.

Comment: It is clear, and I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time complexity of your code is O(²).

Some remarks on your analysis:

> ```
> ll = list(l)  // big O => O(1)
> ```

The `list` function (in Python) creates a new list, so this is actually O()

> ```
> continue   // big O => O(?)
> ```

The `continue` statement takes constant time to execute, so O(1). However, where you use `continue`, you can simply delete those statements, as they have no effect (they are already the last statement executed in the current iteration of the loop).

> ```
> print(ll) // big O => O(1)
> ```

Printing a list takes as much time as the list is long (every single character needs to be output), so this is O(). On the other hand, printing is not something that should be part of complexity analysis. You should better write your algorithm as a function, which just *returns* the result. It is up to the caller to decide whether that list should be printed or not, and anyway that is not part of the algorithm and should not be analysed.

The main question is how many times the loop makes an iteration. If we discard the `if` block that starts with `if x > y`, then `a` and `b` get values that are all the possible pairs you can take from {0,..,−1} where  `a < b`. So for example, if  is 4, the values for `a` and `b` evolve like this:

| iteration | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |

So there are 3 iterations where `a` 0, 2 iterations where `a` is 1, and 1 iteration where `a` is 2. This makes a total of 1+2+3+...+−1 iterations, which is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) and can be expressed as (−1)/2, which is O(²).

O(²) is the *worst case* complexity, because the `if x > y` block may cause `a` to increase faster than explained above. In the *best case*,  your input would be a decreasing sequence ([5, 4, 3, 2, 1]), and then this `if` block will execute in every iteration of the outer loop, so that you only get −1 iterations of the outer loop, which makes it O().

### Code improvements

In Python it is considered better practice to not have explicit `a += 1` statements on the loop variable, but use iterators or ranges to loop over. For instance, the same logic is implemented by this code:

```py
def solve(l):
    return [
        0 if any(l[b] < x for b in range(a + 1, len(l))) else x        
        for a, x in enumerate(l)
    ]
```

Here `any` is used to find out if there is any `b` (after `a`) for which `l[b] < l[a]`. If so the value at `a` should be replaced with 0, if not, we keep the original value `x`. This list comprehension creates a new list, and so it combines your `list(l)` call with the logic in the loop.

### Improving the time complexity

We can also use a different algorithm that is more efficient. If we traverse the list *backwards*, then we can track the *minimum* value encountered so far. Whenever we encounter a value that is greater than that minimum, we replace it with a 0. This way we don't have an inner loop, and the process becomes O():

```py
def solve(l):
    low = l[-1]  # keep track of the least value found so far
    result = [
        0 if (low := min(y, low)) < y else y
        for y in reversed(l)
    ]
    result.reverse()
    return result
```

Comment: so if I write the code as a function and I delete " ll = list(l) " and replace the values in the same list. then the time complexity will be O(n)??

Comment: Not only that, but the algorithm needs to change too, like I explained in the last section of my answer, i.e. perform a *backwards* iteration where you remember the minimum value encountered. If you do it like that, it is clearly O(), as you visit each element in the array only once.

Comment: ok, but I have to write algorithm work with some different cases not only replace with 0 or constant. unfortunately some of these cases need to replace with y or x*y. my algorithm work with all these cases but I need way to reduce the time complexity to O(n) like your algorithm if it possible.   thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The same principle should work with other replacement values. If you cannot make it work, you can post a new question with your attempt.